# GUI items and elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i make boxes similar to theses? I would like a X on the top right. Text on the left of it and the text below the image where the black area is. When i click on X it will remove these and the box on the right moves over and takes it place. How might i create this using jquery? is there some kind of GUI and container i could use to automate boxes moving when i close/delete them and etc [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want any fancy animation effects with sliding and such, it's actually just a little CSS:

```
<style>
    .itembox {float:left;}
</style>
```

If all the boxes' widths fit evenly into the container (say, they are each 100px and the container is 300px wide) then they will stack up next to each other until they reach the bounds of their container, and then wrap left and stack again.

```
<div class="itembox"> <a href="#" class="close">x</a> ... </div>
<div class="itembox"> <a href="#" class="close">x</a> ... </div>
<div class="itembox"> <a href="#" class="close">x</a> ... </div>
```

Setting `display:none` will remove that one from the document flow and hide it, so the ones after it will collapse back. In JavaScript, on the click event for the close button, set the appropriate itembox's display to none:

```
$('.itembox .close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.itembox').hide();
});
```

In jQuery, `hide()` sets `display:none`.

Comment: I am not good with JS or CSS. I am not sure what the .close is suppose to mean/do. Do i put a <br> to seperate the text and X from the img? and again between image and title - name? or do i put them in an object? ATM i linked the X image to #close, how do i hide the object when i click on it? maybe a keyword to google would be better then an explanation ?

Comment: @acidzombie24 I edited the example markup to make it more clear. `.close` refers to the class you would assign your close button.

Comment: After dinner i then realized that. oops. I got stuck again then figured out this.parent should be $(this).parent so i tweaked your answer. Thanks for the solution.